# Orchard - Override MVC View in Module

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

In the Orchard docs [Alternates for MVC views](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/#alternates-for-mvc-views), I see that you can override an MVC view in a theme. I am using a 3rd party theme that is using this mechanism to override the user Register.cshtml template. I am writing a custom module that is adding some fields to the registration page and want to be be able to override the template from my module. I am doing this by inheriting from the AccountsController and then providing my own version of Register.cshtml. This works fine until I enable the 3rd party theme which then overrides my template. Is it possible to have the MVC view in my module take precedence over the one in the theme?

I can always inherit my theme and put my template there, but I'm not crazy about putting something specific to my module in my theme.

Comment: No, but why don't you just delete that template from your theme?

Comment: I can. Was just trying not to edit the 3rd party theme for the sake of future updates.

Comment: That would be true of modules, but themes are bound to be modified. They're also rarely updated in comparison to modules.

Comment: The alternative might be to create another theme using the third  party's theme as it's base theme and just add the alternate you need for your module there.